# How to prevent Axios from encoding my request parameters?

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios

I'm trying to pass in an API key through the URL parameters in my GET request.

However, I notice that Axios encodes the characters in my API key when sending the request. This causes the API to reject my request as it couldn't recognise my key.

How can I prevent Axios from encoding my GET parameters?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use a custom param serializer as follows:

```
axios.get('https://foobar.com/api', {
  paramsSerializer: function(params) {
    var result = '';
    // Build the query string 
    return result;
  }
});
```

`paramsSerializer` can be set at the instance level:

```
var instance = axios.create({ paramsSerializer: function(params) { /* ... */ } })
```

or at the global level:

```
axios.defaults.paramsSerializer = function(params) { /* ... */ };
```

Another option is to directly add the api key to the URL:

```
axios.get('https://foobar.com/api?api_key=' + key);
```

You can add additional parameters using the `params' config option:

```
axios.get('https://foobar.com/api?api_key=' + key, {
  params: {
    foo: 'bar'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you are using [qs](https://github.com/ljharb/qs) library (or similar encoding lib) you can also do

```js
import qs from 'qs';

axios.get('https://foobar.com/api', {
    params,
    paramsSerializer: (params) => qs.stringify(params, { encode: false }),
});
```

Comment: This solution no longer seems to work AxiosError: options must be an object.
paramsSerializer seems to require encode and serialize keys now.

Answer (score 1):

As marko424 answered, you also can do it globally on axios create:

```
import qs from 'qs'

const axios = axios.create({
    paramsSerializer: params => qs.stringify(params, { encode: false }),

})
```

this avoids you need to repeat the code in every axios call.