# Axios GET Request Param with Whitespace

Tags: javascript, react-redux, axios

### Goal

I want to pass query params for a GET request using `axios`. The param value is a variable of type string and has whitespace.

### Problem

It seems `axios` is encoding the param in a format that my backend does not understand. I have done research on `axios` encoding and it appears `axios` encodes whitespace to a `+` and not `%20`.

#### Example

Let's say you have this request:

```
 const whitespace = "white space";
 const encodeWhitespace = encodeURI(whitespace);
 const noSpace = "no";

 axios.get('/api', {
   params: {
     'foo': 'bar',
     'bar': 'hello world',
     'space': whitespace,
     'encode': 'hello%20world', 
     'encoded': encodeWhitespace,
     'simple': noSpace
   }
}
```

The params `foo, bar, encode, simple` all work and generate a response with the correct data. The params `space, encoded` do not generate the correct data. The request is successful with 200 but returns no data.

I created the same request in Postman with the same queries to see if the `GET` returns the expected result and it does. I added the `%20` in Postman and it returns just fine. I added the `+` in Postman and that returns the expected result as well.

### Question

What might be going wrong with the variable implementation? I can't do it without the variable like the `bar` param because the value is being passed to a function (Redux action). Any ideas or thoughts on this would be helpful. Please comment if more information is needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39116731/how-to-prevent-axios-from-encoding-my-request-parameters

Comment: Thank you @marko424. Should I just close this one?

Comment: yes I think we could close this one

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Seems like this is [an issue (or the default parameter serialization behavior)](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1111) of Axios library.

So to overcome this, you have 2 options.

1. Define your query params in the URL itself

```
const whitespace = "white space";
axios.get(`/api?space=${whitespace}`);
```

2. Write your own `paramsSerializer` to build the query string.

```
const whitespace = "white space";
const encodeWhitespace = encodeURI(whitespace);
const noSpace = "no";

axios.get('/api', {
    params: {
        'foo': 'bar',
        'bar': 'hello world',
        'space': whitespace,
        'simple': noSpace
    },
    paramsSerializer: (params) => {
        // Sample implementation of query string building
        let result = '';
        Object.keys(params).forEach(key => {
            result += `${key}=${encodeURIComponent(params[key])}&`;
        });
        return result.substring(0, result.length - 1);
    }
});
```

> Note: The above `paramsSerializer` can be defined in the global level or Axios instance level as well.

- Global level

```
axios.defaults.paramsSerializer = (params) => { /* ... */ };
```

- Instance level

```
let axInstance = axios.create({ paramsSerializer: (params) => { /* ... */ } })
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried the first method before (I forgot to put that in my question) and it does not work. I saw your second method on axios' github issues and that method has not worked for me. :( Not sure what a good alternative would be here. The entire app uses axios so this is quite the bummer.

Comment: I tested both approaches and both of them correctly sent the query params by replacing whitespaces with `%20`. What is the query string sent across when you used the 2nd method?

Comment: Udith Gunaratna, is the param serializer you provided in your answer complete? I added that directly to the source and it did not work.

Comment: Note : `substr` has been deprecated, it's better to use `substring`, read the difference here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring#the_difference_between_substring_and_substr

Comment: @FayçalBorsali Thanks, I updated the answer

Comment: This does not work for me for whatever reason. Any updates?